# need further explanation of "no symbols have been loaded" error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, symbols

I have seen the posts on this site about the following error:
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

But, the problem descriptions and solutions haven't addressed the situation I am experiencing so, I hope to get some clarification.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and working on a very large, somewhat old ASP.NET web application that targets .NET v2. The first page of the application is Login.aspx. If I put a break point on the first line of code within the Page_Load event of the Login.aspx page. I get the yellowed-out warning icon on the break point, with the message above. If, while in debug mode, I go to Debug >> Windows >> Modules, I see that App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.DLL has a Symbol Status that reads "No symbols loaded". The Path for the symbols is like this:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files...\App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.DLL. I have checked that path, and a DLL file does exist there. So, if I right-click on this listing in the Modules page, and select "Load symbols from " and "Symbols Path", I get a dialog box, pointing to the path I just listed but, it is asking for a .pdb file! There is no .pdb file in that directory. Actually there is no App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.pdb file anywhere on my machine.

Also, there is an App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.DLL file located in the bin folder of my project. I was hoping that Visual Studio would generate a new .dll file there if I rebuilt the project. But, if I remove that .dll file, the project won't build.

Very confusing.

How can I get the symbols file situation straightened out?

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can provide.

Special Note: Here is what is listed in the  element of the web.config file:

```
        <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true">
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" extension=".VB" compilerOptions="/define:Debug=True /define:Trace=True /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Configuration,System.Data,System.Drawing,System.Web,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        </compilers>
        <assemblies>...
```

Thanks again for any help...

Comment: Are you running the Debug version of the app?

Comment: I am choosing "Debug >> Start Debugging" so, I assume I am in the debug version of the app. One odd note though...in the Bin folder of the app, there aren't sub-folders called "Debug" and "Release" which is usually the case. The dll and pdb files are placed directly in "bin".

Comment: I'd right click on your project and select "Properties", look at the Build tab to make sure everything looks right, and the "Advanced" button to make sure "Debug Info" is set to Full.

Comment: Also make sure in web.config, you have `<compilation debug="true">`

Comment: Thank you, Mike, for your responses. The application is a Website not a Project so, even if I open it as a Project, I get the Website menu options. I can verify that debug="true" is set in the complitaion element of the web.config file. The compilation element also has a sub element of "compilers". I will post what it says in my original posting.