# Attach To Process w3sp.exe and choosing AppPool

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to use the functionality in Visual Studio 2010 that allows the user to attach to a running process for debugging. I am attaching to the w3wp.exe process. Here is my issue: If I attach to the DefaultAppPool, my break points cannot be hit ("The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"). But, if I connect using Classic .NET App Pool, then my break points work (at least, they did one).

My problem is that the Classic .NET App Pool is not always listed as an option in the Attach to Process dialog box. I have verified that both app pools are running by going to IIS (7) on my machine and checking the App Pools. I have also tried changing the "Attach To:" setting from "Managed (v4.0) code" to "Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0) code". It does not seem to make a difference (I refresh the list after every change).

Can anyone explain why the Classic app pool appears in the Attach to Process list sometimes but not always?

All this is because I have never been able to get the application to debug normally in Visual Studio. ( [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614459/need-further-explanation-of-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-error) ) I worked for days trying to get around the "No symbols have loaded" errors. But, I noticed that when my coworker is debugging the application on his machine (it works for him) he has lots of "Cannot find or open the PDB file" errors in Debug >> Windows >> Modules but, his breakpoints still work. So, I don't think that is the issue.

One note. My coworker is using IIS 6 while I am using IIS 7. I assume that is why the class app pool worked briefly for me. Now if I could attach to it again somehow...

Comment: Thank you for your answers, everyone. I have been able to get it working using the "Attach to process method". Here's how: The website is many up of many smaller applications. It is a site that has existed for years, so it targets ASP.NET 2 framework. I had to go into IIS and make sure that all the applications were using the Classic ASP.NET app pool (some were using default app pool). Then I had to make sure I selected Classic app pool in the Attach to Process dialog. That selection was intermittent because of the mix between Classic and default among the different apps in the site.

Comment: Strangely, the .pdb related issues seem to be a red herring. That is what I have spent so much time trying to resolve, but to no effect. I am currently using an older version of the code (without all those .pdb issues resolved) and it has the breakpoints working. So, Debug >> Windows >> Modules shows lots of "could not find symbols" errors but, the breakpoints work. This is still kind of a mess. But, at least I can debug now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The pdbs need to match the source they were generated from to be of much use. If the module hasn't changed you can sometimes step through but optimally you want to have the matching symbols. The tips I left in my post are what I do. Also, the app pool lets you change the bitness and the framework. If you were to match an app pool to each 'flavor' you might find it easier to open multiple visual studio instances and attach to each site separately (that is until you rewrite everything to be on the same same).

Answer (score 3):

Build the project with a profile that outputs debug PDBs and make sure that debugging is enabled in your web.config via `<compilation debug="true">`.

The app pool you need to attach to is whatever app pool your application is running under, regardless of what the app pool is named.

Answer (score 2):

A few tips:

1) Make sure in the project properties on the Build tab the checkbox 'Optimize code' is turned off. Make sure the pdbs are alongside the assemblies you are trying to debug.

2) When looking for the correct worker process you can run appcmd list wp (as admin) to get the correct process id.

3) Make sure the remote debugger is running (with the proper bitness).

4) Check the modules window and make sure the assembly you are trying to debug is loaded. If not load it (right click).

After trying all that kindly advise.